# How to rollback 'xorg1.13' to 'xorg1.12' in 12.10?

Tags: xorg

My Sound drivers are not recognized by Ubuntu 12.10 and my web search tells me that the upgrade to xorg1.13 is the problem, but I don't know how to roll back the driver (or reinstall) xorg1.12.

Can someone provide me with some instructions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Aptitude can [easily handle rollbacks](http://josh.st/2005/07/23/rollbackdowngrade-using-apt-get/).  **Note that you may have to rollback some dependencies as well**, but the command you are looking for is roughly `apt-get install xserver-xorg=1:7.6+12ubuntu1` (downgrading to the version used in precise).